# TextMate opens two Terminal windows when running a Python script

Tags: python, terminal, textmate

When I tell TextMate to "Run script (Terminal)", two Terminal windows open, one with the program output, another empty (see [screenshot](http://cl.ly/2G2Z1Y2U272i332X2R3Q)). Is there a way to permanently let go of the empty one?

FWIW, TextMate 2 Alpha does the same, but BBEdit 10 doesn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this isn't a problem with TextMate, I think this is a general problem with the apple terminal. On launch it opens a new Window. I think you can deactivate that in the settings. Than that shouldn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a bundle to run Python scripts in Terminal](https://github.com/EugeneDae/Run-in-Terminal-Bundle) which addresses this problem and as well retains focus on TextMate window.